# Fadein AJAX loaded in page

Tags: jquery

I've got a history API script that uses jQuery to load in the new content from a page. How can I fadein the newly loaded div titled `#load`?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',

    dataType: "html",
    success: function (responseData) {

        $("#main").html($("#load", responseData).html());
        if (url =='Home'){

            $.get("phpscripts/getFeed.php",function(result){
                $("#newsFeed").html(result);
            }); 
        }

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can try to use Jquery.fadeIn() . http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 1):

This line needs changing

```
  $("#main").html($("#load", responseData).html());
```

It says get the html INSIDE `#load` but won't include `#load` itself

Try:

```
 $(responseData).find('#load').appendTo( "#main").fadeIn();
```

ALso, make sure you aren't repeating ID's in page. From prior post I believe you may be. ID's must be unique

Answer (score 0):

Found answer, was trying to fadeIn `#load` when should have been `#main`. Thanks to @charlieftl for pointing me in the right direction!